# Convert byte array to structure in the Compact Framework

Tags: c#, struct, windows-mobile, compact-framework, arrays

I need to convert a byte array to my structure type. To do this I use the following code for desktop project application:

```
var str = new SFHeader();
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);

IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, ptr, size);
str = (SFHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SFHeader));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

return str;
```

Where `SFHeader` is my structure.
The problem is that the line:

```
str = (SFHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SFHeader));
```

throws a `NotSupportedException` when I run this code from a smart device project. Are there others methods to do this work in the Compact Framework?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SFHeader
{

    internal const int MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 32;


    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH)]
    public string FileName;

    public int Offset;

    public short Size;

    public byte Flags;

    public byte Source;

    public long LastWriteTime;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Marshal.PtrToStructure works and I've used it many times in the compact framework. it looks like you are using it correctly. Therefore, the problem must be your struct definition (something might not be supported in the CF for the struct)

The following code runs just fine on my device using Windows CE 5.0 and .NET CF 3.5

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SFHeader
    {
        internal const int MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 32;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH)]
        public string FileName;
        public int Offset;
        public short Size;
        public byte Flags;
        public byte Source;
        public long LastWriteTime;
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        var str = new SFHeader();
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, ptr, size);
        str = (SFHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(SFHeader));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
```

I would check to make sure you are following these guidelines [Marshaling Structures in the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172512%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Another option is to copy the fields from your buffer to your structure manually byte by byte. You could write a function that returns a SFHeader and takes a byte[].

Comment: @Nick Hmm.. Do you have the C definition of the header as well?

Comment: @Nick Yeah I thought it might help. Everything you've posted looks alright. The only difference to your code and code I know of mine that works is your Marshal.SizeOf(str) I would have used Marshal.SizeOF(typeof(SFHeader)) but I do not think that should matter. Also, I was curious about the MarshalAs usage relative to your unmanaged type. So I was hoping to compare your unmanaged types to managed struct

Comment: @Nick I know you aren't doing any interop there.. so not sure that it would help. I'm going to run this code on my device see what happens

Comment: @Nick See my update, I ran the code and it seems to work. Perhaps it is the contents of your buffer causing the issue